# Retrieving each variable posted by AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am storing my `checkbox` selections in an array then splitting each array and posting them using AJAX so my `PHP` function can use the posted `id/ids` to query my `MySQL` database.

First part of my JavaScript

```
$('#tbl_list').click(function (event) {
    var tbls = new Array();
    $("input:checkbox[name='tbl[]']:checked").each(function () {
        tbls.push($(this).val());
    });
    var tbl = tbls.join('|');
    alert(tbl);
```

This first part works as intended, where every time I click a `checkbox` the value is alerted.

AJAX post

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: "tbl=" + tbl
    });
});
```

Finally my PHP

```
    function describeTables() {
                if (isset ( $_POST ['tbl'] )) {

                    $tbl = $_POST ['tbl'];
                    echo $tbl;

}}
```

I don't get any vlaues of `tbl` even if I choose just one option. Why is this????

**EDIT**
My Checkbox

```
function showTables() {
        if (isset ( $_GET ['db'] )) {
            $db = $_GET ['db'];
            $link = mysqli_connect ( 'localhost', 'root', '', $db );

            $qry = "SHOW tables";
            $tbl_list = mysqli_query ( $link, $qry );
            echo '<ul>';
            while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $tbl_list ) ) {
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="tbl[]" class="tbl_list"   value="' . $row [0] . '" class="tablebox" />';
                echo $row [0];
                echo '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
    showTables ();
```

**SECOND EDIT**

After suggestions I have amended my code but now have a new problem where the page doesn't load `#dbdisplay` Below is my full JS code

```
if (!location.search.match(/db=[^&#]+/i)) {
    $("#dbdisplay").show();
} else {
    $("#qryDisplay").show();
}

$(document).on("change", ".checkbox", function () {
    var db = $(this).val();
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("db", db);
    window.location.assign("index.php?db=" + db);
    $("#dbdisplay").hide();
});

$('#tbl_list').click(function (event) {
    var tbls = new Array();
    $("input:checkbox[name='tbl[]']:checked").each(function () {
        tbls.push($(this).val());
    });
    var tbl = tbls.join('|');
    //alert(tbl);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data:  {'tbl': tbl }
    });
});
```

The old function

```
 /*
    $(document).on("change", ".tablebox", function () {
        var tbls = new Array();
        $("input:checkbox[name='tbl[]']:checked").each(function () {
            tbls.push($(this).val());
        });
        var tbl = tbls.join('|');
        var yourDB = window.sessionStorage.getItem("db");
        window.location.assign("index.php?db=" + yourDB + '&tbl=' + tbl);
    });
    */
```

How do I fix this??

Comment: looks like `tbls` / `tbl` is a local variable to your `click` function. When do you call the post? Is it inside this function?

Comment: Yes its inside the function, I have now removed the function after suggestions

Answer (score 0):

In ajax call, data has to be object `data: {'tbl': tbl}`

Answer (score 0):

You should use "{ }" with data

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data: {'tbl' : tbl}
 });
```

or

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "index.php&tbl="+tbl
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing in your ajax call, data has to be object

```
data: {'tbl': tbl}
```

Secondly Ajax can't call php function directly 
so your index.php file should be something like this without function

```
 if (isset ( $_POST ['tbl'] )) {
    $tbl = $_POST ['tbl'];
    echo $tbl;
 }
```

Comment: Edited the OP please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This should to the job

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "someurl",
    data: {"tbl=" + tbl}
 });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

See here for documentation

Comment: Edited the OP pls have a look